# Gradle build slow in Bamboo server

Tags: tomcat, gradle, spring-boot, bamboo

A project build with gradle scripts. There are some tests that will need to launch an application context.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ExceptionTestApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles("headerCheck")
@WebIntegrationTest({ "server.port=0", "management.port=0" })
public class ExceptionTest {
```

This project can be built within 1 minutes in local, but takes tens of minutes at a server. After printing the debug information of the build, I found that the step eats the time.

**Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [447,031] milliseconds.**

```
09:25:01.630 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     2015-06-06 09:25:01.628  INFO 27681 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [447,031] milliseconds.
```

The weird thing is that this step never appear when building at local, so I am really confused.

- How and why SecureRandom is invoked when building on server?
- How to configure the server, so that can achieve the build speed just as local?

Answer (score 0):

> How and why SecureRandom is invoked when building on server?

This is hard to guess and depends on the details of your build, but see below for some pointers.

> How to configure the server, so that can achieve the build speed just as local?

The reason for the slowness is the lack of [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(computing)#Security) on the server, which is an important requirement for cryptographic functionality:

> Entropy can affect the [cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography) (TLS/SSL) of a server: If it is too low then the regeneration of codes can take a long time to complete.

Servers in general and cloud servers in particular suffer from the lack of user input and other common random entropy sources that and need to compensate for that accordingly.

#### Background

Here are some links with more information and various approaches how to deal with it (but see below for a possible immediate solution):

- [Low Entropy on EC2 instances - Problem for anything related to security](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=249079)
- [How can you securely generate keys on AWS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44241/how-can-you-securely-generate-keys-on-aws)
- [Helping The Random Number Generator To Gain Enough Entropy With rng-tools (Debian Lenny)](http://www.howtoforge.com/helping-the-random-number-generator-to-gain-enough-entropy-with-rng-tools-debian-lenny)
- [Entropy, or Lack Thereof, in OpenStack Instances (and how to improve that)](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2012/10/entropy-or-lack-thereof-in-openstack.html)

### Solution

You just need to ensure that your server has sufficient entropy available. How to achieve that depends on your runtime environment of course, in particular the OS. Personally I'm using something like the following for our [Amazon Linux AMI (CentOS based)](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/) Bamboo agents:

```bash
# Seed entropy
sudo yum install rng-utils -y
sudo rngd -r /dev/urandom -o /dev/random
```

After seeding entropy like that, it should be considerably higher than before  - test as follows:

```bash
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
```

#### Amazon Web Services (AWS) random generator

If you happen to use AWS anyway, you could also use the dedicated [GenerateRandom](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_GenerateRandom.html) API action provided by the [AWS Key Management Service (KMS)](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/), which is claimed (elsewhere, do not have the reference right now) to provide high quality random numbers applicable for cryptographic purposes.

- The 'high quality' claim has been conceptually challenged, because their algorithm isn't documented, which isn't the proper approach from a transparent security perspective indeed - despite this valid criticism, I would personally trust AWS to get this right though, not the least due to having an extensive proactive and usually well documented approach to [security](http://aws.amazon.com/security/).